# How can I improve my question on hold for being "too broad" so that it is re-opened?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

When I logged in today hoping to see new answers, I was surprised when I found that my [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58693/how-to-build-a-flexible-and-scalable-system-for-pcs-npc-organizations) was on hold.  The notice has flagged it as too broad.  There was one comment suggesting that system-agnostic is an inappropriate tag, but that is it.

To the six users who put my question on hold, what do you find too broad about it, and what can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just guessing.  From the "too broad" definition:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I don't think there's too many answers to this, but if you want someone to write in an answer a small-to-giant-crunchy-org-management solution it'd be too much.  I think that's easily tweaked for asking for preexisting rulesets that meet your criteria.

If the problem is "what you want is too big I don't think something like this exists" (which is likely), this is an incorrect use of close-too broad. Open with no answers is the proper response. Remember voters, "too broad" doesn't mean "he's looking for something too broad in scope to be likely," it means "the question as posed is too broad to answer in this format," and those are very different things.

Comment: You've nailed the reason behind my close vote - this is asking for someone to write an entire system. If it were asking for where a system fulfilling requirements could be found, I'd vote to repoen without a qualm.

Comment: the system agnostic tag is also an issue. You clearly want whatever system you come up with to work with Dark Heresy. This effectively makes it a question about homebrew or third part published material for that system, and narrowing it down to this would stop good answers being too long for the site's format

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure the system-agnostic tag is a problem, actually. There are sys-agnostic realm management rules (but they're very abstract). What's unlikely is *detailed* realm management rules that are actually system-agnostic. It's not impossible though, and actually makes it incredibly narrow, so as this answer says: the correct response is open with no answers (assuming the homebrew aspect is eliminated), not closed as too broad.

Comment: The system agnostic tag is not an issue.  That's covered by my second "maybe there's not one but that's fine mind your business" clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!  I'm accepting this answer, and will be editing the original question.

Comment: From my experience, this site tends to answer with non-answers just so there are no unanswered questions... So "open and unanswered" seems highly unlikely to me...

Comment: @Jason_c_o That can be a problem - we have a lot of users convinced of their Uber RPG Knowledge who like to answer anything.  The solution there is to hold answers to Good Subjective, Bad Subjective and downvote answers that are speculating instead of conveying experience.

Answer (score -11):

Typically, you can't.

Mods and others simply lambaste the author and never revisit it, even if you do a complete overhaul, especially if someone was offended by the question.

The other irritating part is other users will quickly down-vote a question (or an answer), many times without any indication as to why, and never up-vote after an edit by the original author that complies with the suggestions made in the comments that do exist.

While I don't think this is intended, it's how it works in practice. You'll have much better luck if you delete the original question and resubmit as a new question, using the suggestions made by mods and others.

Comment: I disagree with the majority of this view, but particularly the first part dealing with reopening closed questions. The mechanics of the site ensure that an edited closed question gets queued for review for reopening, and certainly from what I've seen people are generally very keen to help get closed questions into shape so that they can be reopened

Comment: Ignoring all the other problems with this answer, resubmitting a question rather than fixing it is against site policy and actively discouraged.

Comment: @Miniman Wyrmwood is suggesting the question get resubmitted *with* improvements. That's something we actually *suggest* people do sometimes when they have a totally recoverable question under the weight of a lot of downvotes, so as to get away from its previous context.

Comment: Generally we do want them to fix their question, and prefer that the option to post it fresh be kept as an exception rather than the default response.

Comment: If you resubmit your question when the previous one is on hold, it is very likely to just up and be deleted. Don't do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then to just delete the question on hold and *then* re-post?

Comment: No, as that loses history and thus context - and it's unlikely the question would be fixed in that transition, leading to more question-discussion anyway. Edit your original questions in almost all cases. Appearance of trying to avoid question critique/downvotes by deleting and respawning will result in disciplinary action.

Comment: Can this "queue" be viewed by non moderators? It sounds imaginary to me from my experience.

Comment: It can be viewed as part of the review system if your reputation is above a certain level (I think its 3000?)